# swift3 Ambiguous reference to member subscript

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I know this question has been asking countless times but I am still struggling to find an answer to this. This is the simplest example I have in my code even though the rest of my code is also riddled with this error ever since I upgraded to Swift 3.

```
func generateDummyPlayers(numberOfPlayers: Int32) -> [NSString : Player] {
    var _players = [NSString : Player]()
    if(numberOfPlayers) > 0 {
        for i in 1...numberOfPlayers {
            let name: String = "\(Player.prefix) \(i)";
            let player: Player = Player(name: name);
            _players[name] = player; //Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
        }
    }
    return _players;
}
```

Comment: If your `player` object contains optional value than it might be possible of that kind of error. Most of time that kind of error throws when try to store optional view in dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined your dictionary as `[NSString: Player]` but your key is `String`:

```
var _players = [NSString : Player]()
let name: String = "\(Player.prefix) \(i)"

_players[name] = player // Error
```

If you don't need to interactive with ObjC, use `String`:

```
var _players = [String : Player]()
```

Comment: And if you do need `NSString` then `_players[name as NSString] = player` will work.

Comment: Thank you both soooooooo much

Answer (score 0):

`name`is a String, so it's not an NSString. You could change your method signature to only use String (recommended):

```
func generateDummyPlayers(numberOfPlayers: Int32) -> [String : Player] {
    var players = [String : Player]()
    if numberOfPlayers > 0 {
        for i in 1...numberOfPlayers {
            let name = "\(Player.prefix) \(i)"
            let player = Player(name: name)
            players[name] = player
        }
    }
    return players
}
```

You could change `name` to an NSString when needed (not recommended):

```
_players[name as NSString] = player
```

You could also use more abstraction (but I discourage it, because [`reduce` is less performant due to the struct copy cost](https://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/08/03/arrays-linked-lists-and-performance/)):

```
func generateDummyPlayers(numberOfPlayers: Int32) -> [String : Player] {
    guard numberOfPlayers > 0 else {
        return [:]
    }
    return (1...numberOfPlayers)
        .map({ "\(Player.prefix) \($0)" })
        .reduce([:]) {
            var players = $0
            players[$1] = Player(name: $1)
            return players
    }
}
```